# Magento 2 load JS at the end

Tags: javascript, performance, magento, pagespeed, magento-2.3

could somebody help me how/in which files can I edit the order of loading scripts? My product page (only the product page) is VERY slow, and I'm trying to load JS at the very end.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code as to what you mean.

Comment: I got an advice, that I should load the JS files at the and of the page, but I don't know how to do it. It is a standard Magento 2 (2.3.3) installation with porto theme: https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo5_en/ if this is what you mean
Product page: https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo5_en/men-stripe-crew-socks.html
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have magento 2.3.2+ you can enable move javascript to bottom of page by following this steps

**Store** > **Configuration** > **Advanced** > **Developer** > **Javascript Settings** and set yes for **Move JS code to the bottom of the page**

[image: Move JS code to the bottom of the page]

if you have older magento version you can use some extensions listed in github to deferejs loading like this one 
https://github.com/taoufiqaitali/magento2-defer-parsing-of-javascript

Comment: yes, I just found it yesterday too, thanks for the answer!